# Starting ActiveMQ 5.11 on Mac OS X 10.10.2

Tags: activemq-classic

I get an error trying to start activemq 5.11.
Perhaps it's related to this issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4299

```
dave@vishnu.local:~/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.11.0/data$ cat wrapper.log 
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:29:01 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:29:01 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/02/09 11:29:02 | Error: Could not find or load main class org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:29:02 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:29:06 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2015/02/09 11:29:06 | Error: Could not find or load main class org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:29:07 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:29:11 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2015/02/09 11:29:11 | Error: Could not find or load main class org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:29:12 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:29:16 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2015/02/09 11:29:16 | Error: Could not find or load main class org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:29:17 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:29:21 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2015/02/09 11:29:21 | Error: Could not find or load main class org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:29:21 | JVM exited while loading the application.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:29:21 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:29:21 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:29:21 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:32:28 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:32:28 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/02/09 11:32:29 | Error: Could not find or load main class org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:32:29 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:32:34 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2015/02/09 11:32:34 | Error: Could not find or load main class org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:32:34 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:32:38 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2015/02/09 11:32:39 | Error: Could not find or load main class org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:32:39 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:32:43 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2015/02/09 11:32:43 | Error: Could not find or load main class org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:32:44 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:32:48 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2015/02/09 11:32:48 | Error: Could not find or load main class org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:32:49 | JVM exited while loading the application.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:32:49 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:32:49 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2015/02/09 11:32:49 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: How are you starting it? unzipping it and running `$ ./activemq start` works for me

Comment: No! It's not related to that issue, since that one is resolved way back in time. ActiveMQ runs fine with using the macosx wrapper out of the box from a vanilla download. Your issue has to be related to some config issue on your local system. It's impossible to tell what without more info and research from your end.

Comment: I ran $ sudo port upgrade outdated and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested, your issue is not related to AMQ per your log:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding activeMQ bin directory to the PATH environment variable.

```
C:\Tools\apache-activemq-5.14.2\bin
```